# Code speed up for an R function using purrr

Tags: r, purrr

I have a function I wrote that I call `tidy_stat_tbl()`

It takes in a data.frame/tibble from my package TidyDensity and will return a statistic of a users choosing on a vector they choose.

I am running `rbenchmark` right now on a 1k replications which I suspect will take 2.5 - 3 hours which is fine, i'll just see the results in the morning.

For a speed up comparison I ran the following:

```r
library(TidyDensity)
library(tidyverse)
library(tictoc)

x <- mtcars$mpg

te <- tidy_bootstrap(x) %>%
  bootstrap_unnest_tbl()

tic()
s <- tidy_stat_tbl(.data = te, .x = y, .fns = IQR, .return_type = "vector")
toc()
0.58 sec elapsed

tic()
l <- tidy_stat_tbl(.data = te, .x = y, .fns = IQR, .return_type = "list")
toc()
0.56 sec elapsed

tic()
t <- tidy_stat_tbl(.data = te, .x = y, .fns = IQR, .return_type = "tibble")
toc()
6.36 sec elapsed
```

When the `.return_type` is set to `"vector"` then `sapply` is run, when set to `"list"` `lapply` is run.

The code that is taking very long and I wish to speed up is the following:

```r
  if (return_type == "tibble") {
    ret <- purrr::map(
      df_tbl, ~ func(.x) %>%
        purrr::imap(.f = ~ cbind(.x, name = .y)) %>%
        purrr::map_df(dplyr::as_tibble) %>%
        dplyr::select(2, 1)
    ) %>%
      purrr::imap(.f = ~ cbind(.x, sim_number = .y)) %>%
      purrr::map_df(dplyr::as_tibble) %>%
      dplyr::select(sim_number, name, .x) %>%
      dplyr::mutate(.x = as.numeric(.x)) %>%
      dplyr::mutate(sim_number = factor(sim_number)) %>%
      dplyr::rename(value = .x)
    
    cn <- c("sim_number","name",func_chr)
    names(ret) <- cn
  }
```

Structure of `te`

```r
 str(te)
tibble [50,000 × 2] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ sim_number: Factor w/ 2000 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ y         : num [1:50000] 17.8 32.4 17.8 19.2 15.8 15.5 15 21.4 10.4 16.4 ...
 - attr(*, ".num_sims")= num 2000
 - attr(*, "distribution_family_type")= chr "continuous"
 - attr(*, "tibble_type")= chr "tidy_bootstrap"
 - attr(*, "dist_with_params")= chr "Empirical"
```

I would love to speed the `purrr` portion up if possible, just not sure where to start or how really.

Here is some sample output of the function:

```r
head(s, 3)
sim_number_1 sim_number_2 sim_number_3 
         5.0          7.8          7.6 

head(l, 3)
$sim_number_1
[1] 5

$sim_number_2
[1] 7.8

$sim_number_3
[1] 7.6

head(t, 3)
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  sim_number  name   IQR
  <fct>      <dbl> <dbl>
1 1              1   5  
2 2              1   7.8
3 3              1   7.6
```

Comment: You can profile your code with [`profvis`](https://github.com/rstudio/profvis/) to find out which part is slow and start from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code helped speed up the by 50%

```r
  if (return_type == "tibble") {
    ret <- purrr::map(
      df_tbl, ~ func(.x) %>%
        purrr::imap(.f = ~ cbind(.x, name = .y)) %>%
        purrr::map_df(dplyr::as_tibble) 
        #dplyr::select(2, 1)
    ) %>%
      purrr::imap(.f = ~ cbind(.x, sim_number = .y)) %>%
      purrr::map_df(dplyr::as_tibble) %>%
      dplyr::select(sim_number, name, .x) %>%
      dplyr::mutate(.x = as.numeric(.x)) %>%
      dplyr::mutate(sim_number = factor(sim_number)) %>%
      dplyr::rename(value = .x)
    
    cn <- c("sim_number","name",func_chr)
    names(ret) <- cn
  }
```